# Node.js app begins timing out (ETIMEDOUT) when HTTP connecting to other sites after having been running for some time

Tags: node.js, request

I connect to other websites in my node.js app using the request module in a very standard manner:

```
Network.prototype.httpRequest = function(url, method, params, headers, callback)
{
    var qs = typeof params === 'string' ? params : querystring.stringify(params || {}),
        config = {
            'method': (method || 'get').toUpperCase(),
            'url': url,
            'timeout': this.app.api.settings.http.timeout_outbound
        };
    if(config.method === 'GET')
    {
        config.url += '?' + qs;
    }
    else
    {
        config.body = qs;
    }

    request(config, callback);
};
```

After a few hours of my app being alive, this function begins timing out -- and not just to one website. It begins to fail to connect (`ETIMEDOUT`) randomly, without any discernable pattern.

My first, obvious guess is that something must be somehow blocking/interfering with the network connections. There are plenty of other "moving parts" in my app (eg, connecting to Mongo via Mongoose, connecting to ElasticSearch via Elastical, etc.), so it is perhaps conceivable that one of them is the cause... but obviously, it's not really an option sit around selectively disabling other modules and waiting 6 hours to see if the problem goes away...

I'm monitoring network traffic (via iStatMenus pro on OSX, FWIW) and do not see any unusual / persistent traffic coming from node.

Is there any other way to delve into what might be blocking / interfering with my traffic?

Comment: have you solved that issue? i've got the same problem...

Comment: i'm also interested in solution ...

Comment: I also have the same issue. Can you tell us what solution fixed it for you?

Comment: Is there a solution? Still having this issue with Node.js 0.12.5

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [setting keep-alive](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_request_setsocketkeepalive_enable_initialdelay) to true? It sounds like the connection is timing out (because you've explicitly set a timeout) when no data is received. I ran into a similar problem while creating a socket server/client solution and this was the fix.

(also, I may have misunderstood the question)

Comment: I highly, highly doubt this is the problem, given that the app works fine for several hours, and nothing is changing about the conditions under which is running except the amount of time it has been running. More specifically, the question is: why would it not be receiving data? THAT's the problem. It shouldn't be happening, especially not with any regularity.